# I want to change url structure of my created archieve pages

Tags: customization, url-rewriting, urls

i have created custom template in which i have run query from database . in  the page i have run loop from database

so i am taking id through url to another page and the link is creating like this 
so i want to change this link from this

```
https://www.taxnetwork.in/single-share-file/?file_id=1
```

to this

```
https://www.taxnetwork.in/single-share-file/file_name/
```

code is here

```
<?php
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM  share_files where status = 1 '));

foreach ($results as $r)
{
    $item_name = $r->title;
    $item_description = $r->description;
    $img_path = $r->img_name;
    $download = $r->file_path;
    $cat_id = $r->category;
    $file_id = $r->id;
    $date = $r->post_date ;
    $cat_res = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM  wp_files_cat where file_id = '.$cat_id .''));
    ?>
    <div class="row" style=" margin:20px 0 ;border-bottom:1px #d8d8d8 dashed">
                <div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs">
               <a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url') ?>/single-share-file?file_id=<?php echo $file_id ?>"><img src="<?php echo $img_path ?> "></a>
                </div>
```

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try add_rewrite_rule(), here's tutorial on how to use it https://www.pmg.com/blog/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/

Comment: When the link is gone/dead the answer is useless. Why not adding the answer here?

Comment: I am not getting how to do that ! can u please create rewrite rule function here for me